# Sum Duration Across Appropriate Intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help. I have a table of individual contacts (i.e. phone calls) that contains the arrival time and the duration. I need to be able to count the number of contacts received in each 15 minute interval, as well as sum the "Talk Time" across each interval. The answered count will peg in the interval in which it arrived, and the appropriate portion of the duration will count at each interval in which the "clock was running" for the contact.

For example, a contact arrives at 2018-12-06 07:15:01.000, lasts for over 15 minutes (947 seconds). How would I get 900 seconds to appear in the 7:15 interval, but the remaining 47 seconds to appear in the 7:30 interval?

Below is a bit of test data in the form of a CTE.

I've got the 15 minute interval part figured out, but I have no idea how to tackle the duration sum. I've tried a few things but my brain gets stuck. I might be able to figure it out eventually, but the direction I take on this project hinges on whether I can get this beat quickly. I know it is possible because the built in report viewer on the source GUI can do it.

I would sure appreciate any help I can get.

```
;with cteTestData as (
SELECT 1 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:03:27.000' as ContactStartTime, Sum(Left('00:04:28',2) * 3600 + substring('00:04:28', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:04:28', 7,2)) as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:03:32.000' as ContactStartTime, Sum(Left('00:14:28',2) * 3600 + substring('00:14:28', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:14:28', 7,2)) as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:08:12.000' as ContactStartTime, Sum(Left('00:10:03',2) * 3600 + substring('00:10:03', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:10:03', 7,2)) as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:14:59.000' as ContactStartTime, Sum(Left('00:02:58',2) * 3600 + substring('00:02:58', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:02:58', 7,2)) as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:15:01.000' as ContactStartTime, Sum(Left('00:15:47',2) * 3600 + substring('00:15:47', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:15:47', 7,2)) as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:15:12.000' as ContactStartTime, Sum(Left('00:08:18',2) * 3600 + substring('00:08:18', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:08:18', 7,2)) as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT 7 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:18:50.000' as ContactStartTime, Sum(Left('00:10:22',2) * 3600 + substring('00:10:22', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:10:22', 7,2)) as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT 8 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:20:05.000' as ContactStartTime, Sum(Left('00:03:11',2) * 3600 + substring('00:03:11', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:03:11', 7,2)) as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT 9 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:29:32.000' as ContactStartTime, Sum(Left('00:32:53',2) * 3600 + substring('00:32:53', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:32:53', 7,2)) as Duration
UNION ALL
SELECT 10 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:35:17.000' as ContactStartTime, Sum(Left('00:07:37',2) * 3600 + substring('00:07:37', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:07:37', 7,2)) as Duration
)
select ID, ContactStartTime
, DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF( minute, 0, ContactStartTime) / 15) * 15, 0) AS ContactStartInterval
, Duration

FROM cteTestData
ORDER BY ContactStartTime
```

EDIT: Here is the updated query from Squirrel with added notes.

```
    ;with 
cteTestData   /*this will not be necessary in the production query, as this CTE will be replaced with the actual source table*/
as 
(
    SELECT 1 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:03:27.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:04:28',2) * 3600 + substring('00:04:28', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:04:28', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:03:32.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:14:28',2) * 3600 + substring('00:14:28', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:14:28', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:08:12.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:10:03',2) * 3600 + substring('00:10:03', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:10:03', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:14:59.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:02:58',2) * 3600 + substring('00:02:58', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:02:58', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:15:01.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:15:47',2) * 3600 + substring('00:15:47', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:15:47', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:15:12.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:08:18',2) * 3600 + substring('00:08:18', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:08:18', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:18:50.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:10:22',2) * 3600 + substring('00:10:22', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:10:22', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:20:05.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:03:11',2) * 3600 + substring('00:03:11', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:03:11', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:29:32.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:32:53',2) * 3600 + substring('00:32:53', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:32:53', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:35:17.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:07:37',2) * 3600 + substring('00:07:37', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:07:37', 7,2)) as Duration
),
cteIntervalNumbers as /*tally table to generate a number for each interval*/
(
    SELECT  num = 1
    union all
    SELECT  num = num + 1
    FROM    cteIntervalNumbers
    WHERE   num < 99
)
,
cteTimes as /*CTE to calculate ContactEndTime, ContactStartInterval, ContactEndInterval*/
(
    SELECT  ID, ContactStartTime
          , Duration
          , DATEADD(second, Duration, ContactStartTime) AS ContactEndTime
          , DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF( minute, 0, ContactStartTime) / 15) * 15, 0) AS ContactStartInterval
          , DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF( minute, 0, DATEADD(second, Duration, ContactStartTime)) / 15) * 15 + 15, 0) AS ContactEndInterval
    FROM    cteTestData /*this will be the source table*/
)
SELECT IntervalStart, count(DISTINCT ID) as Contacts, SUM(DurationInterval) as TalkTime
FROM (
SELECT  *
        ,
        CASE    
        /*all of the time exists in the interval; just find the difference in start and end, which will be the entire duration*/
        WHEN  ContactStartTime >= IntervalStart AND ContactStartTime < IntervalEnd
        AND   ContactEndTime >= IntervalStart AND ContactEndTime < IntervalEnd
        THEN  DATEDIFF(second, ContactStartTime, ContactEndTime)
        /*contact carries over into next interval; get time between the start time and the end of that interval*/
        WHEN  ContactStartTime >= IntervalStart AND ContactStartTime < IntervalEnd
        AND   ContactEndTime > IntervalEnd
        THEN  DATEDIFF(second, ContactStartTime, IntervalEnd)
        /*this will get the elapsed time in the carry over intervals where the contact ends within that interval*/
        WHEN  ContactStartTime < IntervalStart 
        AND   ContactEndTime >= IntervalStart  AND ContactEndTime < IntervalEnd
        THEN  DATEDIFF(second, IntervalStart, ContactEndTime)
        /*this is for all intervals where the contact neither starts nor ends i.e. where the full elapsed time of the interval is needed*/
        ELSE  DATEDIFF(second, IntervalStart, IntervalEnd)
        END AS DurationInterval
FROM    cteTimes d
        CROSS JOIN cteIntervalNumbers n
        CROSS APPLY /*this calcualtes the start and end time for each interval that the contact crossed*/
        (
            SELECT   DATEADD(minute, (num - 1) * 15, ContactStartInterval) AS IntervalStart
                    ,DATEADD(minute, num * 15, ContactStartInterval) AS IntervalEnd
        ) i
/*only show intervals crossed by each contact*/
WHERE   n.num <= datediff(minute, ContactStartInterval, ContactEndInterval) / 15 /*how many intervals does the contact cross?*/
) rawdata
GROUP BY IntervalStart
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer to in-query comments for explanation.

Basically it checks for how much time it falls within the interval

```
|--------|---------|--------|     interval
    S...E                         [1]
    S....                         [2]
          ....E                   [3]
          .........               [4]


;with 
cteTestData   -- Your Sample Data
as 
(
    SELECT 1 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:03:27.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:04:28',2) * 3600 + substring('00:04:28', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:04:28', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:03:32.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:14:28',2) * 3600 + substring('00:14:28', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:14:28', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:08:12.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:10:03',2) * 3600 + substring('00:10:03', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:10:03', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:14:59.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:02:58',2) * 3600 + substring('00:02:58', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:02:58', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:15:01.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:15:47',2) * 3600 + substring('00:15:47', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:15:47', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:15:12.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:08:18',2) * 3600 + substring('00:08:18', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:08:18', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:18:50.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:10:22',2) * 3600 + substring('00:10:22', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:10:22', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:20:05.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:03:11',2) * 3600 + substring('00:03:11', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:03:11', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:29:32.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:32:53',2) * 3600 + substring('00:32:53', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:32:53', 7,2)) as Duration
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 as ID, '2018-12-06 07:35:17.000' as ContactStartTime, (Left('00:07:37',2) * 3600 + substring('00:07:37', 4,2) * 60 + substring('00:07:37', 7,2)) as Duration
),
numbers as       -- recursive CTE as number / tally table
(
    SELECT  n = 1
    union all
    SELECT  n = n + 1
    FROM    numbers
    WHERE   n < 99
),
cte as          -- CTE for calculate ContactEndTime, ContactStartInterval, ContactEndInterval
(
    SELECT  ID, ContactStartTime
          , Duration
          , DATEADD(second, Duration, ContactStartTime) AS ContactEndTime
          , DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF( minute, 0, ContactStartTime) / 15) * 15, 0) AS ContactStartInterval
          , DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF( minute, 0, DATEADD(second, Duration, ContactStartTime)) / 15) * 15 + 15, 0) AS ContactEndInterval
    FROM    cteTestData
)
-- the main query. 
SELECT  *,
        CASE    
        -- [1]
        WHEN  ContactStartTime  >= IntervalStart    AND ContactStartTime    < IntervalEnd
        AND   ContactEndTime    >= IntervalStart    AND ContactEndTime      < IntervalEnd
        THEN  DATEDIFF( second, ContactStartTime, ContactEndTime)
        -- [2]
        WHEN  ContactStartTime  >= IntervalStart    AND ContactStartTime    < IntervalEnd
        AND   ContactEndTime    > IntervalEnd
        THEN  DATEDIFF( second, ContactStartTime, IntervalEnd)
        -- [3]
        WHEN  ContactStartTime  < IntervalStart 
        AND   ContactEndTime    >= IntervalStart    AND ContactEndTime      < IntervalEnd
        THEN  DATEDIFF( second, IntervalStart, ContactEndTime)
        -- [4]
        ELSE  DATEDIFF( second, IntervalStart, IntervalEnd)
        END AS DurationInterval
FROM    cte d
        CROSS JOIN numbers n
        CROSS APPLY  -- this calcualtes the start and end time for each interval
        (
            SELECT   DATEADD( minute, (n - 1) * 15, ContactStartInterval) AS IntervalStart
                    ,DATEADD( minute, n * 15, ContactStartInterval) AS IntervalEnd
        ) i
WHERE   n.n <= datediff(minute, ContactStartInterval, ContactEndInterval) / 15
ORDER BY ContactStartTime, n
```

Comment: This appears to do what I need. I am still dissecting the code so that I fully understand what is going on. I was on this track of repeating all intervals for each contact so I could compare, but got lost in the logic. I am curious though, what if i already had a table with each interval throughout the day (time portion only)?  How would that change your approach?

Comment: OK, I think I understand this now. I have added notes in my own words and changed some aliases to mean more to me. I would like to repost the code for you to look at, but cannot figure out how. I don't post on Stack Overflow very often.

Comment: you can edit your question and post the final query there

Comment: Final query added.